# hide username and password in curl command shell script

Tags: bash, shell, authentication, curl

I use the below curl command to disable the alert which works fine.

```
curl -k -u admin:password https://URL -X POST
```

But i am trying to hide the username and password in the below shell script but getting unauthorized exception,

```
SCRIPT_DIR=/tmp

USER=$(cat $SCRIPT_DIR/.nonprodusr.txt)

PWD=$(cat $SCRIPT_DIR/.nonprod.txt)

curl -k -u $USER:$PWD https://url -X POST
```

Comment: I would check the variables with i.e. `printf %s "$USER"`, to see whether they contain spaces or linefeed characters.

Comment: Also make sure you quote your vars: `curl -k -u "$USER":"$PWD" https://url -X POST`

Answer (score 1):

One can use a configuration file to add user/password as well as other configurations.

```
curl --config /home/me/curl-configuration.txt <url>
```

Contents of "/home/me/curl-configuration.txt":

```
--user <username>@<password>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `netrc` file : https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/netrc

`/tmp/netrc` :

```
login admin
password Passw0rd
```

And use it with this option :

`curl -k --netrc-file /tmp/.netrc https://url -X POST`

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have 50 reputation, I wasn't able to comment on @nvd answer but wanted to extend it anyway.

I had to change the contents of `/home/me/curl-configuration.txt` to:

```
--user <username>:<password>
```

This is mentioned in the manpage of [curl](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html):

```
-u, --user <user:password>
    Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.
    Overrides -n, --netrc and --netrc-optional.

    If you simply specify the user name, curl prompts for a password. 
    [...]
```